# Change injection in Autofac module with a mock (Moq) object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac, autofactory

I have a Autofac module as below

```
    public class ServiceInjector:Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
            {
                // many registrations and type looking up here
                ...
                // One of the registration, say t which is found
                // in above looking, is a resource consuming type

                builder.RegisterType(t).As<ITimeConsume>();

                // ...
            }
    }
```

And this module is used in a ServiceClass:

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    static IContainer _ioc;
    public ServiceClass()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<ServiceInjector>();

        _ioc = builder.Build();     
    }

    public void InvokeService()
    {
        using(var scope = _ioc.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            ITimeConsume obj = scope.Resolve<ITimeConsume>(...);

            var result = obj.DoTimeConsumingJob(...);

            // do something about result here ...
        }    
    }
}
```

My questions is: how do I test ServiceClass by mocking (Moq) ITimeConsume class ? Here I try to write a test below:

```
public void Test()
{
    Mock<ITimeConsume> moc = GetMockObj(...);

    // How can I inject moc.Object into ServiceInjector module,
    // so that ServiceClass can use this mock object ?
}
```

If this is not possible for the way, what's a better design for mocking the time consuming class which can also be injected?

**

### Update:

**
Thanks @dubs and @OldFox hints. I think the key is that the Autofac injector should be initialized externally instead of internal controlled. So I leverage '[On Fly](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html?highlight=fly#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope)' building capability of Autofac.ILifetimeScope and design ServiceClass constructor with a LifeTime scope parameter. With this design I can on-flying registering any service in the unit test as below example:

```
using(var scope = Ioc.BeginLifetimeScope(
    builder =>  builder.RegisterInstance(mockObject).As<ITimeConsume>())
```

Answer (score 4):

In the current design you cannot inject your mock object.
The simplest solution with the least changes is to add an `Internal` Cto'r to `ServiceClass`:

```
internal ServiceClass(IContainer ioc)
{
    _ioc = ioc;     
}
```

Then use the attributte [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to enable the using of the C`tor in your test class.

In the arrange/setup/testInit phase initialize your class under test with the container which contains the mock object:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        Mock<ITimeConsume> moc = GetMockObj(...);
        builder.RegisterInstance(moc).As<ITimeConsume>();
        ...
        ...
        _target = new ServiceClass(builder.Build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have multiple container instances. One for each endpoint.

#### Test project

```
public class AutofacLoader
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterModule<ServiceProject.ServiceInjector>();
        builder.RegisterModule<LocalTestProject.AutofacModule>();

        Container = builder.Build();
    }

    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }
}
```

The local test project autofac module is then free to override the service project module with specific registrations.

> If more than one component exposes the same service, Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider of that service: http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations

#### Test class

```
public void Test()
{
    AutofacLoader.Configure();

    var x = AutofacLoader.Container.Resolve<ITimeConsume>();
}
```